# alloy predicate calculus post production

Tags: alloy

As I'm new to alloy, this is most likely a simple question.  I've been through the on-line tutorials and am now reading the Software Abstractions, revised edition.  On page 34 there is an example at the bottom of the page:

```
r' = {b:B, a:A, c:C | a->b->c in r}
```

where the text says that this defines a new relation of B->A->C.  I don't see how an explicit order for r' is achieved by this statement.

Answer (score 1):

It's the property of set comprehension

- `{a: A | somePredicate1[a]}` is of type `A` and returns a set containing all atoms for which `somePredicate1` holds;
- `{a: A, b: B | somePredicate2[a, b]}` is of type `A->B` and returns a relation containing all `a->b` tuples for which `somePredicate2` holds;
- and so on

The syntax of set comprehension basically consists of two parts (1) type declaration (before the `|` character), and (2) predicate which must hold for every element in the returned set.